# Assembly code to system functions (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, assembly, system, system-calls

possibly a really dumb question, but could someone explain why one could not write assembly code to trigger system functions or control hardware? For example, would it not be possible to write code to switch screen off/on or even the device's phone?

I am not talking about jailbreaking the device, nor making an app for the app store. Normal app with assembly to call system functions.

If indeed possible, anyone have a good reference or starting point of achieve such tasks?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible using Android NDK.

Comment: sorry you missed the iPhone header...

Comment: I suspect only the operating system of the iPhone.

Comment: are you talking about actual PIN IO? As in you would need the data sheet for the processor (which is completely proprietary)? Is so surely it would seem possible to find some asm code to talk with the physical pins but it would be fairly difficult to get ahold of the proper protocol that apple uses... also its possible they have a security check to verify the process running has permissions in order to talk to the pins..

Comment: Well no I was more think about system calls by address range execution. Not PIN IO as such. If I have a legit app signed and all and I execute functions (system or hardware) at given addresses should it not be possible to do? Jailbreaking in essence allows you to exactly that, but I am wondering what are schematics behind a normal call via assembly without a jailbroken phone/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhones use a memory-protected operating system in which each user process is contained in its own virtual memory address space.  The address space is protected by the memory management unit (MMU) hardware and trying to access memory outside of regions given to the process by the OS will result in an exception.  The OS reserves hardware memory ranges to itself and does not make it available to user processes.  As such, it is not possible to directly interface to the hardware from a user process.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to call system functions from assembly code. And what do you think a C or C++ application does? It does exactly that. C/C++ and assembly code all ultimately convert (at compile time) into machine code that the CPU executes.

I'm not sure where the guide would be for doing things like this, but you can certainly run a C program in a debugger and see how it calls various system functions or you can disassemble this program and read the disassembly without running the program in the debugger.

In any event, you will not get more control over the device from a program written in assembly than from a program written in C. The OS should restrict direct access to certain I/O devices and memory areas at the CPU level, where there's no distinction between assembly and C, it's all the same to the CPU, just a bunch of instructions in machine code.

Comment: Note that the sandbox and many many other restrictions besides the one you're noting keep those functions from doing what they are actually supposed to do (this is for security reasons). Also objective c is in fact just c code, nothing too fancy about it when you get down into its insides

Comment: I am possibly very dumb or naive. Back in the "old days" I knew that setting hardware flags/addresses you could manage hardware. Ie. eject your CD tray via a given memory call. Now ignoring the OS these calls surely lie somewhere in the memory range so that the OS can call them as well. I am guessing that the overhead of identifying the caller of this calls is simply not viable at assembly level, so again, why would someone not be able to execute them? The only thing I can think of is the kernel not allowing it but you are not making kernel calls... Sorry I might be missing something.

Comment: Back in the old days, CPUs were um... dumb. These days, general-purpose CPUs have various protection and security features and the OS can configure the CPU to have unrestricted access to everything for itself and limited access for user-level applications. Most often this means that there's a subset of the CPU instruction set that only the OS can execute and the OS configures the MMU (typically, page tables) in such a way that only certain regions of memory can be read and executed from and written to by applications.

Comment: Clearing the fog for me Alexey !!! Thank you heaps. Simple poke commands in other words not possible/simple.